# Aiogram 3.2.0 pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for InlineKeyboardMarkup how to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

How to fix error with aiogram 3.2.0

pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for InlineKeyboardMarkup

inline_keyboard
Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/missing

```
faq = InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'FAQ', callback_data="faq")
event = InlineKeyboardButton(text = '‼️event‼️', callback_data='event')
prof = InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'profile', callback_data='prof')
main_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(prof,event).add(faq)
```

Comment: can you provide the complete code

Comment: error code or my entire bot

Comment: if you give me a small part that works in this case maybe i can try it and find the answer

Comment: it works on aiogram 2.25.2 but doesnt at 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
main_kb = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
faq = InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'FAQ', callback_data="faq")
event = InlineKeyboardButton(text = '‼️event‼️', callback_data='event')
prof = InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'profile', callback_data='prof')
main_kb.add(faq, event, prof)
main_kb = main_kb.as_markup()
```

Or:

```
main_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
[InlineKeyboardButton(text = "FAQ", callback_data="faq"),
InlineKeyboardButton(text = "‼️event‼️", callback_data="event"),
InlineKeyboardButton(text = "profile", callback_data="prof")
]
],)
```